# Angular - Update scope when change in Factory data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a factory to poll a particular web service. This web service is used to update data any the factory. I initiate this factory in the main controller, and populate a scope variable through a factory function. The variable initializes correctly, and I get the right data on the screen, but I'm struggling on getting the data to bind automatically.

Edit for additional notes:
The reason this code is in a Factory is that I plan on using the factory data across multiple views.

Here is what I have so far:

```
App.factory('metrics', function($http, $q, $timeout){
    var service;
    var users = [{laps:[]}];
    var updateMetrics = function(){
        //updates the users array in the factory
    };
    service.load = function (){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('http://www.example.com/api/random').success(function(data) {
            var temp_array = data.split("\n");
            updateMetrics(0, temp_array);
            deferred.resolve({status: 'good'});
            $timeout(service.load,3000);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    service.lastLapInfo = function(){
        var lastlap = [];
        for (var i=0; i<users.length;i++)
        {
            var lap = users[i].laps[users[i].laps.length-1];
            lastlap.push(lap);
        }
        return lastlap;
    };
    return service;
});

App.controller('mainController', function($scope, metrics) {
    metrics.load().then(function(response){
        $scope.$watch(function () { return metrics.lastLapInfo() }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !=oldVal)
            {
                $scope.users=metrics.lastLapInfo();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I try the above, I get an error saying '10 $digest() iterations reached'. I don't see how that's possible, asI'm not calling the watch function multiple times.

Any suggestions (or other means to accomplish what I'm trying to do?)

Comment: Is your typo in `$service.load` (prefixing `service` with `$`)  also present in your project?

Comment: Apologies - the syntax is correct in the project, but must have messed it up during the copy/paste. I've edited the question to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not 100% set on using `$watch`, a pattern that I prefer is to bind new instances of (not references to) modules to the current scope and keep the controllers strictly as components used for wiring together the project's views and models. This excludes the use of `$watch`, even for coordinating data across modules. I prefer to use `$rootScope`'s `$broadcast`, `$emit` and `$on` methods within modules/factories (after passing in `$rootScope` as a service, which may or may not work for all situations, though it has for all that I've come across) rather than the comparatively sluggish `$watch` or `$watchCollection` methods. Using the latter makes me feel dirty inside... But I digress.

Would something like the following work in your situation?

```
App.factory('metrics', function($http, $q, $timeout){
    var service;
    service.users = [{laps:[]}];
    service.updateMetrics = function(){
        // updates the users array in the current instance of `metrics`
        // ex:
        // this.users = updatedMetrics;
        // don't do:
        // service.users = updatedMetrics;
    };
    service.load = function (){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('http://www.example.com/api/random').success(function(data) {
            var temp_array = data.split("\n");
            this.updateMetrics(0, temp_array);
            deferred.resolve({status: 'good'});
            $timeout(service.load,3000);
        }.bind(this));
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    service.lastLapInfo = function(){
        var lastlap = [];
        for (var i=0; i<this.users.length;i++)
        {
            var lap = this.users[i].laps[this.users[i].laps.length-1];
            lastlap.push(lap);
        }
        return lastlap;
    };
    return service;
});

App.controller('mainController', function($scope, metrics) {
    $scope.metrics = angular.copy(metrics);

    $scope.metrics.load();

});
```

By setting `$scope.metrics = angular.copy(metrics)`, we are creating a new instance of `metrics`, rather than setting `$scope.metrics` as a reference to `metrics` (`$scope.metrics = metrics`). This has several benefits, including that you can now use multiple instances of the same module in the controller (ie `$scope.foo = angular.copy(foo); $scope.bar = angular.copy(foo);` since the objects bound to `$scope` are completely new objects, rather than references to the same module.

Another benefit is that the instance of `metrics` attached to `$scope` can be used to call methods on `metrics` which can allow any changes to `metrics` to automatically be applied to your controller's views. I frequently faced odd issues when trying to get this to work when not using `angular.copy` or `$.extend`, seemingly because changes to the referenced module attached to `$scope` were not always being registered.

Comment: I'm open to any option that works to be honest. I looked through the code but I'm not really sure how extend works in this case. From reading the angular docs, it seems to me that extend just does and object copy from source to destination. Additionally, In the answer above it looks like we have an additional parameter (true). Could you give me a quick overview to what is going on?

Comment: I've changed the code to use `angular.copy` rather than jQuery's `extend` method, which are totally interchangeable (to my knowledge). The answer has been edited with an overview.

Comment: +1 for leveraging the already existing AngularJS eventBus ($rootscope) for this.

Comment: @WalterRoman - I just realized this, but should have mentioned it earlier - the reason this code is in a Factory is because I want to use the data across multiple views. Wouldn't creating a new instance of metrics stop my from using the same factory across the views?